# $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading Serre's Trees and in Example 1.5.3 he claims that $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_3$.

$\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_3 = \langle x, y | x^2 = y^3 = 1 \rangle$. But does $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ even have elements of order $2$ or $3$ to begin with?

Previously, I thought since all elements of $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is in the form of 
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}. $$ 
Hence $\mathbb{Z}$ injects in $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. 
Let $\phi: \begin{bmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \mapsto n$. 
$\phi$ is a homomorphism and in fact bijective. Hence $\mathbb{Z} \cong PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. 
Thus $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ cannot have any $2$-torsion or $3$-torsion.

I must be missing something. Any help is appeciated!

Comment: Why do you think those are all the elements in $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$? What about e.g. $\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&3\\1&2\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: Also, one easy element of order 2 in $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is $\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: I think you need to check the definition of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. And $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is an element of order $3$.